# Why libmysqlclient.21.dylib is needed on local with only mysql5.7 running?

Tags: python, mysql

On my local I've got mysql@5.7 running. And I have an application which relies on mysql, but got interesting error:

```
    File "/xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
    ImportError: dlopen(/xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
    Referenced from: /xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    Reason: image not found
```

1. Now only mysql@5.7 runs on my local, so I can see I've got `/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib`, but I never have `/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib`. And why is it needed here? `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` is only provided by `mysql8.0+`
2. What is `site-packages/MySQLdb` doing? Guess connect to my local
   mysql? Then why it's asking `21.dylib` which doesn't exist?

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same issue (using python 3.8), and thanks to [Bill Karwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176829/9074500) was able to fix it by reinstalling `mysqlclient` with `—-no-cache` option, to make sure the wheel gets rebuilt:

```bash
pip uninstall mysqlclient
pip install —-no-cache mysqlclient
```

Here is the sequence of events that led to the `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` error in my case:

- installed `mysql` via Homebrew, which installed `mysql@8`
- pip-installed a bunch of dependencies for a project, including `mysqlclient`
- realized I actually needed `mysql@5.7` for the project, downgraded `mysql`
- ran the project and saw the error about missing `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` because the `mysqlclient` wheel was built while `mysql@8` was installed

Comment: Exactly what happened and this solved it!

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb is a Python 2 module implemented in C, and it links to the libmysqlclient. If you have a binary of MySQLdb that was compiled against a MySQL 8.0 client library, then it would have a fixed reference to libmysqlclient21.dylib, and if that library is not present, that would cause the error you saw.

MySQLdb is also not compatible with Python 3, and [I would hope you use Python 3 by now](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

You can use PyMySQL as a substitute for MySQLdb. PyMySQL is all-Python, so it should not reference any libmysqlclient.

Alternatively, use [MySQL-Connector Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/).

Comment: Thanks. It seems MySQLdb is from mysqlclient library, where my app depends on mysqlclient:1.3 version. But I'm still confused about "compiled against MySQL 8.0 client library", because I'm using mysql@5.7, how come there's 8.0 client lib?